# Richfaces style classes redefinition

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I spend all day and can't change rich:panel style class. This is the page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .rich-panel{
        border: 0px;
        background: blue;

     }
     .rich-panel-body {
        border: 0px;
        background-color: blue;
        color: orange;
        font-size: 32px;
     }
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <rich:panel>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </rich:panel>

</h:body>
</html>
```

And the result is the same as without adding style classes.

Comment: Those style class names suggests that you're using RichFaces 3.x instead of RichFaces 4.x. Is this true?

Comment: Were you able to identify the CSS using a tool like firebug  or webdeveloper on mozilla ?

Comment: Yes, I've done this. And i found that this style classes are for RichFaces 3.x. The classes for RichFaces 4.x. are rf-p, .rf-p-hdr and .rf-p-b. Can I override them entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change style classes of the rich:panel for Richfaces 4.x we must use rf-p, .rf-p-hdr and .rf-p-b classes. For example:

```
div.rf-p{        
 border: 5px;        
 background: blue;       
}      

div.rf-p-b {         
 border: 0px;         
 background-color: blue;        
 color: orange;        
 font-size: 32px;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You insert this CSS

```
 <style type="text/css">     
div.rich-panel{        
 border: 0px;        
 background: blue;       
}      

div.rich-panel-body {         
border: 0px;         
background-color: blue;        
 color: orange;        
 font-size: 32px;      
}    
 </style>
```

Comment: I have tested, It woked for me. You try to use a external CSS file, ex. richfaces.css

Answer (score 0):

rich panel has attributes Style,Styleclass to attach css

```
<rich:panel styleClass="somecssclass">
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</rich:panel>

or

<rich:panel style="border:0px;color:orange">
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</rich:panel>
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to make classes redefinition like here: [link]http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#customstyles

Comment: Use firebug on firefox to see why your styles are being overriden by the default ones.

Answer (score 0):

in your html file do this:

```
<rich:panel headerClass="panelHeader"
        bodyClass="panelBody" >
    <f:facet name="header">This is the Header Label</f:facet>
</rich:panel>
```

your css should look like this:

```
.panelHeader {
 background-image: url();
 background-color: #87d6ed;
 height: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.panelBody {
 background-color: #bdf0f0;
 height: 8px;
 width: 130px;
 overflow: auto;
}
```