# How check/uncheck all checkboxes from a list

Tags: javascript, checkbox, richfaces

This is the code of a list of checkboxes:

```
<div class="span8">
    <h:panelGrid id="columnGrid" width="450">
        <rich:orderingList id="columnlist" value="#{EquipReportBean.settings}" listWidth="400" listHeight="250" var="item">
            <s:convertEntity />
            <rich:column>
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.show_column}" id="showColumn"/>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.column_id.name}" id="columnName"></h:outputText>
                </rich:column> 
        </rich:orderingList>
    </h:panelGrid> 
</div>
```

I ve already found a lot of about JavaScript in the internet about checking/uncheckin all. But the problem here it's that I don't have all the checkboxes IDs to check through code. How can I do the function to check or uncheck all of them using another checkbox. Thank you!

Comment: You should respond to answer to see if they are good or not, accepted or not.

Answer (score 2):

I've already done that with RichFaces and jQuery years ago, that should do the trick in your case :

```
<rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
       <input type="checkbox" onclick="jQuery(#{rich:element('columnlist')}).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',this.checked);" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.show_column}" id="showColumn"/>
</rich:column>
```

**More info :**

- [RichFaces Component References Functions](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

Add the same styleClass to your checkboxes ( [Richfaces style classes redefinition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095528/richfaces-style-classes-redefinition) ):

```
styleClass="checkboxToCheckClass"
```

Then through javascript (jquery here) :

```
jQuery('.checkboxToCheckClass').attr('checked', true);
```

This link can help you : [Using jquery to get all checked checkboxes with a certain class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450104/using-jquery-getting-all-checked-checkboxes-with-a-certain-class-name)

Comment: By default you can't use `$()` with RichFaces.

Comment: Ok, I just have tried once richfaces. But perhaps, the styleClass trick can help him. Your answer will certainly be more helpful.